# Flask already disable CSRF but self.errors still have the error "'csrf_token': ['CSRF token missing']"

Tags: python, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

I have the following view which logins a user. I am using flask-wtforms for forms.

```
def login(self, username, password):
    return self.app.post('/users/login', data=dict(
    email=username,
    password=password
    ), follow_redirects=True)
```

I have already disabled CSRF in my configuration:

```
class Config(object):
SECRET_KEY = .....
DEBUG = True
TESTING = True
CSRF_ENABLED = False
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = .......
```

but I still get the error `{'csrf_token': ['CSRF token missing']}`in `self.errors`

What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 4):

Which version of FLask-WTF are you using?

Prior to version 0.9.0 you use CSRF_ENABLED. [Source](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/v0.8.4/#configuring-flask-wtf). Versions >= 0.9.0 use WTF_CSRF_ENABLED. [Source](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#forms-and-csrf).

Comment: I used v0.8.3 before,and i didn't realize that the document is too old.Now i am using the latest version

Comment: That should have fixed it then.

Answer (score 1):

i have found solution in the latest document of flask-wtforms(the doc i read is too old)
the config should be WTF_CSRF_ENABLED not CSRF_ENABLED

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest version as of December 2015 (v0.12) then you should replace `SECRET_KEY = ...` with `WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY = ...`